# From the digits 0, 1, 2, ... 9 randomly choose three digits. What is the probability that these three digits can be used to write:

Tags: probability, probability-theory

From the digits 0, 1, 2, ... 9 randomly choose three digits. What is the probability that these three digits can be used to write:

a) at least one three-digit odd number

b) exactly one three-digit odd number

c) exactly two three-digit odd numbers

Here is my try:

a) $1 - \frac{\binom{3}{5}}{\binom{3}{10}} = \frac{11}{12}$

This doesn't lead me to a solution of b) but I tried to take one odd digit and any two of the remaining digits dividing by all 3 choices of digits $\frac{\binom{1}{5} * \binom{2}{9}}{\binom{3}{10}}$ to get probability of at least one odd and any two digits but it seems to be $\frac{3}{2}$. Help me understand what is wrong.

Update:
b) Now I realize that in order to get exactly one three-digit odd number i need to have 0, any odd and any even digit, so it will be $\frac{\binom{1}{5} * \binom{1}{4}}{\binom{3}{10}} = \frac{1}{6}$

c) I need 0, and two odd digits then probability will be $\frac{\binom{2}{5}}{\binom{3}{10}} = \frac{1}{12}$, it matches the answer but I still have my doubts

Comment: This needs clarification. $1$. Are these numbers chosen with or without replacement? $2$. Does $029$ count as a three-digit odd number, or would it have to be $209$ (if you chose $0, 2, 9$ as your three digits)?

Comment: The reason your answer for b) is too large is that the set of odd digits from which you chose the odd digit and the set of remaining digits are not disjoint.  Therefore, you are counting numbers with more than one odd digit multiple times, once for each way you could designate one of those odd digits as the odd digit in the number.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Will this formula be correct $\frac{\binom{1}{5} * \binom{2}{5} + \binom{2}{5} * \binom{1}{5} + \binom{3}{5}}{\binom{3}{10}}$ ?

Comment: @BrianTung 1. I don't know, i can just say true answers for this exercise from the book: a) $\frac{11}{12}$ b) $\frac{1}{6}$ and c) $\frac{1}{12}$ 2. I think $029$ whould not be a number

Comment: The given answer for c is not correct. Selections such as $\{0,1,3\}$ and $\{2,4,5\}$ will work, but it seems the source only considered the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question b)

There are four cases:
CASE 1 you have no odd numbers (p = 1/12),
CASE 2 you have one odd number (p=5/12),
CASE 3 you have two odd numbers (p=5/12),
CASE 4 you have three odd numbers (p=1/12).

The only way in which you can create exactly one three-digit odd number is in CASE 2 when one of the two even numbers is 0. The probability that one of the even numbers is 0, is $\frac{4}{2 \choose 5} = \frac{2}{5}$. So the probability that you can create a three-digit odd number equals $\frac{5}{12}.\frac{2}{5} = \frac{1}{6}$

Question c)

This can only happen in CASE 2 (p=5/12) where you have one odd number and additionally none of the other numbers are zero (p = 3/5), or in CASE 3 (p=5/12) where you additionally have one zero (p=1/5). this combined yields a probability of $\frac{5}{12}.\frac{3}{5} + \frac{5}{12}.\frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{3}$